# Find repeated elements occuring more than Once

Tags: arrays, matlab, find-occurrences

I have an array `A` as follows:

```
A = [7 7 10 10 10 15 1 1 15 15 7 16 17 1 18]. ';
```

How can I obtain all numbers which occur more than one times in my array? In this example the answer should be `1 7 10 15`.

Comment: Its unclear. Why is 1 not there and 7 is?

Comment: It's a typo sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using the following code

```
[ii,jj,kk]=unique(A);
repeated=ii(histc(kk,1:numel(ii))>1);
```

Comment: This counts elements occurring more than once, not more than twice. You may need to change the last `1` into `2`

Comment: @AdupaVasista So you should edit your question since it does not match your answer. You've specified "more than twice", so `> 2`.

Comment: Moreover If I do `2` instead of `1`, I am getting the result same as the one when I run with the one you posted.

Comment: You may want to replace the unneeded output `jj` with tilde

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach, just for variety:

```
[~, ind] = unique(A);
result = A;
result(ind) = [];
result = unique(result);
```

Comment: Ah, you changed your question. Please see now